# What is the syntax error in my SQL?

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql, sql-update, vb.net-2010

My Command is :

```
sql = "UPDATE tbl_employees SET Username_= """ & TextBox1.Text & """, Password_= """ & TextBox2.Text & """, Temporary=" & False & " WHERE Username_ = """ & EmployeeLogin.loginusername & """ AND Password_ = """ & EmployeeLogin.loginpassword & """"
```

What is the syntax error? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You really need to think about parameterised queries. Your application is open to SQL Injections

Comment: dude it's for a school project that will literally never be touched again after this friday, do you know why its throwing up a syntax error?

Comment: What does the sql variable contain just after the above statement is executed?  With all these quotes it's such a MESS that I really don't feel like decoding it.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: when run the sql contains - "UPDATE tbl_employees SET Username_= "z", Password_= "z", Temporary=False WHERE Username_ = "a" AND Password_ = "a""

Comment: error reads 'Syntax error in UPDATE statement.'

Comment: here is you problem. Change `Temporary=" & False & " WHERE ` to `Temporary= False WHERE `. But never put this code in production

Comment: how do you mean put it in production?

Comment: and still throwing up the same error message with that amended code

Comment: What database is this? Some only allow single quotes around strings.

Comment: using microsoft access

Comment: to add to cha comments regarding parametized; it not only protect against SQL inject but also makes it easier to debug/read instead of trying to read double quote inside double quote/single quote/variable etc in a String variable.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access uses the Jet database engine (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) in which Temporary is a reserved word.  See a list of reserved words here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321266

Put the table name in square braces, like this:

```
[Temporary]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is already posted, but here is some free advice.

When you encounter an error like this, use a debug tool to capture the *actual generated value* in the variable.

- Using a query execution tool, execute the SQL "manually".
- See if the error message points to the problem.
- If not, remove a small part of the SQL from the query, such as `AND Password_ = "blahBLAHblah"` and execute again.
- Repeat the last step until the error disappears.
- The last bit of code removed must be causing the problem.
- Retry the original query with just that one part removed to confirm the problem is there.

It isn't always as simple as this, but a methodical step-by-step approach can usually locate the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

A solution was already posted, but I'll leave this here just for reference. It's  neat and easier to read, using Parameters. This can be used as an alternative for your code. Assuming you use [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) and [TSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) .

```
Dim SqlCmd As String = " UPDATE tbl_emlployees SET Username_ = @username, Password_ = @password, Temporary = @temporary, WHERE Username_ = @myUsername AND Password_ = @myPassword"
        Using execSQLQuery As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strSqlCmd, myConn.dbConn)
            execSQLQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text)
            execSQLQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text)
            execSQLQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@temporary", "False")
            execSQLQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myUsername", MyUsernameVariable)
            execSQLQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myPassword", MyPasswordVariable)

            execSQLQuery.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
```

The `execSQLQuery` is just a temporary variable, after the `Using` it will be just disposed.

Answer (score -1):

try to write AND instead of symbol & in sql

Comment: There is no `&` in the SQL, that is for concatenating strings to create the SQL.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is with the part:

```
Temporary=" & False & "
```

Try changing this to

```
Temporary=0
```

The vb.net boolean type False will be converted to the string representation "False" in that statement which I believe SQL will frown upon.  Assuming your column is a bit column you're better off using 0 or 1.